# Can't access methods in my class

Tags: c#, class, namespaces

I have small class for text files:

```
using System.IO;

namespace My_Application
{
    public static class FileIO
    {
        public static void WriteText(string filename, string text)
        {
            StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(filename);
            file.Write(text);
            file.Close();
        }

        public static string ReadText(string filename)
        {
            StreamReader file = new StreamReader(filename);
            string text = file.ReadToEnd();
            file.Close();

            return text;
        }
    }
}
```

My main file:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace My_Application
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {    
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private string readTestFile()
        {
            // error is here:

            return FileIO.ReadFile("test.txt");
        }
    }
}
```

Im getting error:

> My_Application.FileIO' does not contain a definition for 'ReadFile'

This is weird, because I was using that class in another application and it worked.
Only difference I catched, is that other application had one word name without "_".

Edit/added later:

OK. My problem was bad method name. However this is still weird, because IntelliSense suggests nothing when I write `FileIO.` (i also tried to press ctrl-space).

**Additional question: Why IntelliSense does not see these methods?**

Comment: The method is called ReadText in your example and you are referencing it as ReadFile.

Comment: Do you know about File.ReadAllText / File.WriteAllText, btw? (Also: your current code lacks necessary dispose calls, usually done via "using")

Comment: This is dumbest question I asked on stackoverflow :) However that was weird - when I write `FileIO.` intellisense suggests nothing. Why?

Comment: My advice: try to use Visual Studio IntelliSense before you ask question. It is trivial and there is no point to ask it.

Comment: @pt12lol Im using IntelliSense, but... as I wrote above - it suggests nothing. This is weird...

Comment: @Kamil, in Visual Studio 2012, IntelliSense sometimes breaks and requires you to close and re-open the file and/or Visual Studio to fix it. Also, if there's an error in file, it also sometimes stops working.

Comment: @Kamil: So you had better google something like "Visual Studio IntelliSense not working". I don't know (and I suppose that no one know) why your IntelliSense doesn't work. In my opinion there are no information why it would happen.

Comment: @Sam I just had same idea and I reopened VS. Now it's working fine.

Comment: @pt12lol Well, my IntelliSense was working only for methods in that file/class. How could I know that my problem is caused by IntelliSense?

Comment: @Kamil: "@Sam I just had same idea and I reopened VS. Now it's working fine." - it was good idea also. But you had better start with it. In my opinion Stack Overflow is not for questions like that one yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is called `ReadText` but you're trying to call `ReadFile`.

Declaration:

```
public static string ReadText(string filename)
```

and usage:

```
return FileIO.ReadFile("test.txt");
```

Comment: isn't it better to leave as comment because it's so simple :P

Comment: You are right. In addition - my IntelliSense was broken, until I restarted Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be

```
return FileIO.ReadFile("test.txt");
```

It should be

```
return FileIO.ReadText("test.txt");
```